# Login Failed you cant use facebook to log into this app

Tags: java, android, facebook

I get "Login Failed Error" with the Facebook Android SDK while running on the device. I have done everything what they specified, like creating a hash and all.

The error is:

> Login Failed you cant use facebook to log into this app or website
>   because there's an issue with its implementation of facebook login

Answer (score 8):

We have encountered this same issue before. In our case, it turned out that the Facebook restricted our app due to violating their platform policies. We appealed to Facebook by telling them we are working on making our app to be compliant with their policies. Then they responded to us and removed the restriction temporarily to give us the time to do our testing. After they removed the restriction, we no longer encounter this error message.

Comment: What solution worked? I mean did you remove any facebook permissions ? or updated sdk version

Comment: We only have the facebook default permissions.  If you want other facebook permission, you need to do the facebook app review where you need to tell them why you need those permission.  Previously we are only using JS sdk as we are using the web view in mobile, but we changed to using iOS/Android sdk for this as required by Facebook.  After Facebook verified that our app is using the correct login they removed the restriction completely and now we can use the login. You can always write in to Facebook and ask for extension.